# Oracle connection error with Windows authentication

Tags: windows, oracle, authentication

I'm trying to use the Devart library to connect to an Oracle server using Windows authentication. Basically the client impersonates the Windows user that has access to the database using the LogonUser Windows API function with logon type LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS and then attempts to connect to the server, but the server complains that the user doesn't have permission to access the database (the user does have permission because I can connect to the server using sqlplus client running as that user). I checked the server logs after the connection attempt and I can see that the user trying to connect is the user that started the client, not the impersonated user (so it makes sense that the connection fails). The question is why is this user being used and not the impersonated user as would be expected? It's interesting to note that if the LogonUser function is called with logon type LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK_CLEARTEXT then the connection is done using the impersonated user and the connection works fine. The problem is that we cannot use this logon type because the client needs to access other resources while the connection is open, and under this impersonation mode this is not possible.

This is the connection string being used:

```
data source="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host)(PORT=port)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=serviceName)))";unicode=true;Connect Mode=;Pooling=False
```

I tried adding 'Integrated Security=yes' to the connection string as is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837458/oracle-connection-string-with-windows-authentication) but it complains that 'integrated security' doesn't exist.

To summarize the problem: the client impersonates a user that has permission on the database using LogonUser function and logon type LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS but the connection is done using the user that started the process, not the impersonated user. Why is this happening? I suspect the connection string needs something else, but I can't figure out what it is.

Thanks.

---

**Details:**

**1** Stack trace:

```
Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleException : ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
at Devart.Data.Oracle.an.b(Int32 A_0)
at Devart.Data.Oracle.a.c(Int32 A_0)
at Devart.Data.Oracle.a.a(aj A_0, f A_1)
at Devart.Data.Oracle.ak..ctor(aj A_0, ak A_1)
at Devart.Data.Oracle.c.a(DbConnectionOptions A_0, Object A_1, DbConnectionBase A_2)
at Devart.Common.DbConnectionFactory.a(DbConnectionBase A_0, DbConnectionOptions A_1)
at Devart.Common.DbConnectionFactory.a(DbConnectionBase A_0)
at Devart.Common.DbConnectionClosed.Open(DbConnectionBase outerConnection)
at Devart.Common.DbConnectionBase.Open()
at Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleConnection.Open()
at NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider.GetConnection()
at NHibernate.AdoNet.ConnectionManager.GetConnection()
at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.get_Connection()
```

**2** The "user that started the client" is the user that started the process, e.g. user A. The "impersonated user" is the user that has permission on the database, e.g. user B. User A does not have permission on the database. User B does not have permission to access resources on the machine where this process is running. So process is started as user A, then the process is impersonated to user B to access the database (using LogonUser function and logon type LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS), but the database receives a connection attempt with credentials from user A, not from user B, hence the error "logon denied".

**3** NUnit test.

**4** If I try to connect using sqlplus, it works. Basically I open a command-prompt as user B (from the example on item 2) and run the following command (host, port and serviceName are placeholders here):

```
sqlplus /@"(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host)(PORT=port)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=serviceName)))"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide us the following information for reproducing the issue:

1. the message and stack trace of the exception;
2. what is the difference between 'the user that started the client' and 'the impersonated user'?
3. The type of the application that attempts to establish a connection using windows authentication;
4. The connection string that you use in SQL*Plus;

> ...I tried adding 'Integrated Security=yes' to the connection string as is suggested here but it complains that 'integrated security' doesn't exist....

There is no 'integrated security' connection string parameter. If you want to use Windows authentication, just omit the 'user id' and 'password' connection string parameters. For more information, please refer to http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/?Devart.Data.Oracle~Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleConnection~UserId.html

Comment: Thanks for replying. I edited the post to answer your questions. Regarding your last comment: yes, the connection string does not have userID/password. I just tried 'Integrated Security=yes' because I saw it as an answer in the other question.